# TLS handshake not completing

Tags: python, ssl, tls1.2, handshake, pyopenssl

I have a client and server application with self-signed certificates. The do_handshake method is not working properly. In the client the SSL negotiation is finished successfully, but not on the server. The server says `before SSL initialization` all the time (using `get_state_string()`).

See the code.
Client

```
from OpenSSL import SSL, crypto
import socket

HOST = "localhost"
PORT = 8080

def verify_cb(conn, cert, errnum, depth, ok):
    print(f"Got certificate: %s {cert.get_subject()}")
    print(f"Issued by: {cert.get_issuer()}")
    return ok

# Initialise SSL context:
ctx = SSL.Context(SSL.TLSv1_2_METHOD)
ctx.set_verify(SSL.VERIFY_PEER, verify_cb) # Demand a server certificate
ctx.load_verify_locations("serverpath.pem")
ctx.use_privatekey_file('clientkey.pem')
ctx.use_certificate_file('clientpath.pem')

# Set up client:
sock = SSL.Connection(ctx, socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM))

sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
sock.set_connect_state()
print(sock.get_state_string())
while True:
    try:
        sock.do_handshake()
        break
    except SSL.WantReadError:
        pass
print(sock.get_state_string())
sock.write("HELLO")

# Read response:
while True:
    try:
        print(sock.recv(4096))
    except SSL.ZeroReturnError:
        break
```

Server

```
from OpenSSL import SSL, crypto
import socket

HOST = "localhost"
PORT = 8080

def verify_cb(conn, cert, errnum, depth, ok):
    print(f"Got certificate: %s {cert.get_subject()}")
    print(f"Issued by: {cert.get_issuer()}")
    return ok

# Initialise SSL context:
ctx = SSL.Context(SSL.TLSv1_2_METHOD)
ctx.set_verify(SSL.VERIFY_PEER, verify_cb) # Demand a client certificate
ctx.load_verify_locations("clientpath.pem")
ctx.use_privatekey_file('serverkey.pem')
ctx.use_certificate_file('serverpath.pem')
# Set up sever:
sock = SSL.Connection(ctx, socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM))
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind((HOST, PORT))
sock.listen(1)

print("Waiting for connections.")

#Wait for clients to connect:
(conn, address) = sock.accept()
sock.set_accept_state()
print(f"Got connection from {address}")
print(sock.get_state_string())
while True:
    try:
        print(sock.get_state_string())
        print(conn.recv(4096))
        print(sock.get_state_string())
    except SSL.ZeroReturnError:
        break
```

Please, can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(conn, address) = sock.accept()
sock.set_accept_state()
print(f"Got connection from {address}")
print(sock.get_state_string())
while True:
    try:
        print(sock.get_state_string())
        print(conn.recv(4096))
        print(sock.get_state_string())
```

You need to operate on the accepted socket `conn` and not on the server socket `sock`. While you read from the accepted socket you print the state of the server socket instead, which does not reflect the state of the connected socket. Also, you don't need to set the accept state since you've already called `accept` on the SSL server socket:

```
(conn, address) = sock.accept()
print(f"Got connection from {address}")
print(conn.get_state_string())
while True:
    try:
        print(conn.get_state_string())
        print(conn.recv(4096))
        print(conn.get_state_string())
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!! :)
It is now working. However I still have 2 questions:


1. How does it generally work, should the client or the server call ```do_handshake()```? Have I enforced the handshake properly with my while True loop?


2. Since I removed ```set_accept_state``` from the server, do I also have to remove the ```set_connect_state``` from the client, because I also have previously called the connect function on the SSL socket? In what cases does one have to use ```set_accept_state``` or ```set_connect_state```?

Comment: @Gledi: These functions are useful when doing TLS over an already established connection. You don't need these if you call accept and connect directly on the TLS socket. You also do not explicitly call do_handshake unless you want to have more control when the handshake is done. It will be done implicitly otherwise.

Comment: I get it now! I really appreciate your help, because my actual task is to implement TLS over another protocol and now I understand the differences between a normal TLSSocket and a TLSSocket with a BufferIO hence "over another protocol/established connection". :))